emit nulls vs 0s until non-zero value
This seems like it should be easier than I'm making it...given data that looks like:



day
value




2024-03-01
0


2024-04-01
0


2024-05-01
1


2024-06-01
0


2024-07-01
2



I'd like to emit:



day
value




2024-03-01
null


2024-04-01
null


2024-05-01
1


2024-06-01
0


2024-07-01
2



In other words, convert the 0s to nulls until I get a non-null value.  Or alternatively, I could create the initial data with nulls instead of 0s and convert nulls to 0 once I get a non-null value.
This "works", but seems like there might be a better way.
with  data as (
  select cast('2024-03-01' as date) as day, 0 as value
  union
  select '2024-04-01', 0
  union
  select '2024-05-01', 1
  union
  select '2024-06-01', 0
  union
  select '2024-07-01', 2
),
withsum as (
  SELECT day, value, sum(value) OVER (ORDER BY day) AS cum_amount from data
)
select day,
         value,
         cum_amount,
         case when cum_amount = 0 and value = 0 then null 
              when cum_amount = 0 and value != 0 then 0
              else value end as thevalue
         from withsum


Your query is efficient, but it can be simplified a bit:
WITH data(day, value) AS (
  VALUES (DATE '2024-03-01', 0),
         (DATE '2024-04-01', 0),
         (DATE '2024-05-01', 1),
         (DATE '2024-06-01', 0),
         (DATE '2024-07-01', 2)
)
SELECT day,
       CASE
          WHEN sum(value) OVER (ORDER BY day) = 0
          THEN nullif(value, 0)
          ELSE value
       END AS thevalue
FROM data;

